# Scan QR code in moving vehicle using cordova plugin

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I am working on a cordova application. Is there a plugin available to scan QR code attached in
a moving car window?

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://github.com/bitpay/cordova-plugin-qrscanner) is one of the most popular QR reader plugins.

In order to read it from a moving vehicle you need a phone with an outstanding camera definition, or with an external and really good camera connected with USB OTG cable pointing to the vehicle, this has nothing to do with the plugin.

Comment: is there will be any difference in the detection rate if we increase the fps of video?